# how to load MDI child form only one time when click twice

Tags: c#, .net

I have two forms.
Form 1 is MDI parent form and form 2 is MDI child form.
When I click button 1 in form 1, form 2 will show.
When I click button 1 again and again form 2 load again and again.
How can I stop it?
My code is

```
        frmCashBook cashbook = new frmCashBook();
        cashbook.MdiParent = this;
        cashbook.Show();
```

Comment: That appears to be C++; it's definitely not C. You should also add other tags to specify the environment (Windows?).

Comment: It's not C. It is c#.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, each time you click button1 a new instance of frmCashBook is created and further shown.

You need to keep the declaration outside the button click handler:

```
frmCashBook cashbook;
```

further replace the button1 click handler with:

```
if (cashbook != null)
        {
            // If cashbook is already instantiated (for the case when button1 is clicked again and again after first click)
            cashbook.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // If cashbook is not instantiated (for the case when button1 is clicked first time)
            cashbook = new frmCashBook();
            cashbook.MdiParent = this;
            cashbook.Show();
        }
```

This will make sure whenever button1 is clicked only first click will create a new instance further later clicks will not create any new instance and will just show same instance which was created in very first click.

Comment: It's working. but there is a problem. When I close the form and click open button again form doesn't open. How can i fix it.

Comment: When the instance of 'frmCashBook' is closed the variable 'cashbook' in parent form doesn't reset to null. We need to make sure whenever the child form (here instance of frmCashBook) is closed the variable in parent form holding its reference should be reset to null to resolve this issue. Add following additional statement in else block(above) : cashbook.FormClosing += cashbook_FormClosing;
   Further add following handler definition outside button click handler:  public void cashbook_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
         cashbook = null;
        }